# ¿Cómo acceder a ficheros que se encuentran en storage Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero mandar un e-mail confirmando el registro de los usuarios en el sistema. 
Para ello he configurado el fichero `.env` con los datos del e-mail, he creado una clase Mail en `/app/Mail/NotificationsMessages`, una vista con el diseño del mail y por último invoco la clase luego de confirmar el registro.

Mi fichero `/app/Mail/NotificationsMessages`

```
class NotificationsMessages extends Mailable

{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
     public $subject = "Notificación de Registro";
     public $data;
     public $logo;
     public $linked;
     public $face;
     public $twit;
     public $mailA;
     public $mailB;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
           $this->logo = Storage::url('logo.svg');
         $this->linked = Storage::url('linked.svg');
           $this->face = Storage::url('face.svg');
         $this->twit = Storage::url('twit.svg');
         $this->mailA = Storage::url('mail_A_1.svg');
           $this->mailB = Storage::url('mail_B_3.svg');
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.notification');
    }
}
```

En realidad no sé como acceder a los logos que se encuentran en /storage/app/public/images ni en /storage/app/public/ (he probado ambas y prefiero almacenarlos en la primera opción).
Según la documentación y lo que yo entendí es que se puede usar `Storage::url` previa ejecución de este comando: `php artisan storage:link`

Me da error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_get_contents(/home/desarrollo/Escritorio/Proyectos/miprojecto/resources/views/emails/notification.blade.php): failed to open stream: Permiso denegado
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace el comando `php artisan storage:link` es que crea un enlace que se encuentra en `public/storage` al directorio `storage/app/public/`, por lo tanto, para obtener un archivo lo único que debes de hacer es lo siguiente:

**Tomando en cuenta que para acceder a tu carpeta public no necesitas poner "public" primero**

```
$this->logo = asset('storage/logo.svg');
```

El método `asset()` te devuelve la URL de la ruta que le mandas por parámetro.

Cabe mencionar que para cuando quieres descargar un archivo con el método `download()` de laravel, si necesitarías la ruta absoluta (ya sea que uses `storage_path()` o `public_path()` por dar un ejemplo) y no la URL.

Con respecto a los permisos, asegúrate de que tengan `775` los directorios `storage` y `bootstrap/cache`, sino, modíficalos desde la terminal:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :/ mismo error

Comment: @Carlos imprime la URL que te está devolviendo, cópiala y pégala en el navegador y accede a ella, si te devuelve lo de permiso denegado, entonces aún no has establecido los permisos correctamente.

Comment: bueno, te cuento, ni siquiera me dejaba entrar a misitio/login  pero eso ya lo solucioné. El problema fue asignar permisos 775, para solucionarlo asigné 777 a los directorios que me mencionaste. El problema ahora que no manda ningún correo, ni siquiera diciendo "ok" como funcionaba anteriormente. El error es el siguiente "file_get_contents(/home/desarrollo/Escritorio/Proyectos/misitio/resources/views/emails/notification2.blade.php): failed to open stream: Permiso denegado"

Comment: @Carlos No es correcto asignar permisos `777` ya que cualquier persona mal intencionada tiene permisos de escritura en los archivos con esos permisos. El error que te sale es una cuestión de permisos nuevamente, las vistas normalmente tienen permisos `644`.

Comment: @Carlos Verifica el usuario con el que estás creando los archivos y el usuario que se encarga de ejecutar los archivos.

Comment: he creado un directorio "png" dentro de "public", eso ha resultado ser mas fácil

Comment: @Carlos pero eso no es la solución; la creas con un usuario diferente al que ejecuta apache o php; que tenga privilegios elevados y hasta hay llego la fiesta... inclusive no es lo adecuado... se espera que un profesional sepa colocar todo su setup correctamente con los permisos, owner correctos para la ejecución y no andar creando archivos o repositorios nuevos a diestra y siniestra...